# iOS HTTP multipart-form Streaming Request

Tags: iphone, ios, file-upload, httprequest, nsinputstream

I have to implement a file upload for my app. Files like Assets (which can be Photo or Video) should be uploaded to a web sever using a REST interface.

The upload would use a form data request with custom header attributes.

**Problem:**
Holding large files like Videos in an `NSData` object can lead to memory issues. This would be the standard approach.

**Solution**
Providing an `NSInputStream` for the body part of the request - and write data piece by piece to the HTTP Body Stream.

**Question** Can anyone provide an exmaple of how to use an NSInputStream in combination with a `NSURLrequest` and `NSURLConnection`?

I wrapped my head around several incomplete examples -

but I do not know how to deal with the following method

```
- (NSInputStream *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *)request
```

I don't want to use any third party library.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to use any third party library but you could maybe use them as a reference to see how to perform such tasks ?

You could maybe take a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkingx&) code to see how Mattt achieved such kind of things.

I'd also suggest using Sessions, that are more documented and robust (if the targeted platform makes it available)